# SQL Query with Textbox as reference

Tags: ms-access-2010

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

I just want to do a query wherein the criteria is a value of a text box name 'AgentName'. The form name is 'Issue' with table name is 'Issue_Table'.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
SELECT IssueTracker.Issue from IssueTracker where IssueTracker.AgentAffected = "& Me!Issue!AgentName &"
```

but it doesn't give any error messages nor gives me the result I want.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

It's a string so quotes must be applied, and Me is the form, thus:

```
"SELECT IssueTracker.Issue from Issue_Tracker where IssueTracker.AgentAffected = '" & Me!AgentName & "'"
```

If this is a query, use:

```
PARAMETERS [Forms].[Issue].[AgentName] Text;
SELECT Issue from Issue_Tracker where AgentAffected = [Forms].[Issue].[AgentName];
```

Comment: I'm using the MS Access 2010 Query Design Window in SQL View, so I just pasted that code.. I tried using the one that us just gave but still yields 0 results :(